# Java Library for Creating ISO that's still supported

Tags: library, java, iso

I'm working on a project that involves creating DVD ISO's from data that Java has access to. I can make a system call to something like "mkisofs", but that really affects the portability of the program because it can then only be run on Linux. I'm looking for a Java library that can create and write to an ISO file.

What I have found so far through Googling is "JIIC" - Java ISO Image Creator - which would seem to be perfect, except it looks like it hasn't been updated since 2011. I found it through this answer here: [How to generate an ISO with JIIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750614/how-to-generate-an-iso-with-jiic), which links to SourceForge, which still has some JARs available here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jiic/files/, but the CVS for sourcecode is not available.

However, the actual website, http://jiic.berlios.de/, appears to be down, and the WayBack Machine only has a couple of snapshots - most just redirect to berlios.de, although a page from August 4, 2010 seems to be an actual archive, no real documentation though (http://web.archive.org/web/20100804071736/http://jiic.berlios.de/).

So, are there any libraries still being supported in 2016? I'm a little surprised that I can't find an Apache utility for this, given how ubiquitousness of the ISO disc standard.

(Note: I originally asked this on StackOverflow, but was encouraged to re-ask the question here, since it's a request for a Java library which they call an "external resource". Technically I'd be very happy with an "internal resource", as in I'm really just asking "how do I do this in Java", but since it's not supported natively, I guess I need to make a request here for a software recommendation to get the job done. Please let me know if I've violated any rules in *this* community!)

Comment: Basically the question is good for this site. ISOs have many sub-formats like Audio, ISO9660, Joliet, UDF etc, right? Which ones do you need? Why doesn't the old version work for you? Does it have bugs? Some products (hopefully) are just finished and they don't need maintenance because they're complete and tested.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Joliet is the best for my use-case, but any library would suffice. I actually sent an email to the old maintainer of this code to see if he still has the source - although I haven't found any bugs in general use, I'm uncomfortable relying on a closed-source, unsupported, 5-year-old library for a project. If I were to find a bug, I would not be able to fix it, or even report it. I just wanted to know if anyone had a suggestion for a library that was in active development.

Comment: https://github.com/stephenc/java-iso-tools says it's a fork of JIIC, but I haven't checked this myself. The contributions graph leads me to believe it's not in active development, and that the code is probably essentially unchanged from JIIC. I realize this therefore doesn't meet your requirements, but it might satisfy your source-code longings =)